# gcc __attribute__ with separation of declaration and definition

Tags: gcc

I want to take advantage of GCC's visibility attribute.

To such end, in my executable, I have a function I wish to be visible to any plugins, so they can use it to register themselves. I therefore use `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on it and `-fvisibility=hidden` as an option on the command line.

[This article](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html) seems to imply that attributes can only be used on declarations.

Is it possible to have the implementation of a function in a separate .cpp file and apply the attribute to only the declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is often done that way, the `__attribute__` appears only at the declaration.